# Iterate feature classes to append a folder of shapefiles to their corresponding feature classes in a preset geodatabase template?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, iterator

I want to make a tool with iterate feature classes that will take my shapefile folder and append each shapefile to it's corresponding feature class in a template geodatabase.

I have a folder with shapefiles "**A.shp**", "**B.shp**", and "**C.shp**" and a geodatabase with feature classes "**A**", "**B**" and "**C**".

The geodatabase needs to be a parameter because this is done to many different datasets.

Comment: You would use getparameterastext to set your own parameter.  If you have some code that would be way helpful.

Comment: I'm using ModelBuilder, forgot to mention that. I wouldn't know where to begin with python.

Comment: A screenshot of the model you have so far then would be helpful.  I believe the basic logic is iterate through the folder and use the append tool in no test mode to append to the feature class.  You will set the input GDB as a parameter (right click on it in the model) and select input parameter. see http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/model-parameters.htm

Comment: [![toolscreenshot.png](https://s16.postimg.org/rftubnbz9/toolscreenshot.png)](https://postimg.org/image/jn36jo601/)

Comment: I have the parse path collecting the folder path because the geodatabase is in the same folder. The problem I'm having is selecting multiple feature classes as the target dataset within the append tool.

Comment: sorry I got called out in to the field,  when i get back to the office i will take a look at what you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have the model working now. The only problem I'm having is using the inline variable %Name% while also having the target dataset within append as a parameter

Comment: Had a look at your screen shot of your model. It is currently highly inefficient. The Append tool takes a LIST of datasets, so your Append tool should only run once. As EVERYTHING runs as many times as the iterator loops your Append tool is executing the same number of times. You need your iterator to feed into a Collects tool and that is in a SUB MODEL which feeds into a single Append tool in a MASTER model. Search SE for sub-models to correct it.

Comment: If I am understanding the append tool and the iterator correctly, I WANT it to run more than once because I'm matching multiple shapefiles with multiple feature classes within a geodatabase (A.shp to A feature class, B.shp to B feature class). And I also want to keep them separate.. Using Collect data, extra features are put into my feature class from all of the shapefiles not the corresponding shapefile.